# Symfony 5 PHP8 Attributes for Security

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-security, php-8

I have a page that I am trying to convert from annotations to PHP8 attributes.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[IsGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')]
#[Route('/page')]
class PageController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'page')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('page/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'PageController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

The `IsGranted` attribute doesn't seem to work, as the page is accessible instead of a 403 error. On the other hand when converted to annotations, like below it works as expected. Is there a config setting I am missing?

```
/**
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
 */
#[Route('/page')]
class PageController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'page')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('page/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'PageController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Other attributes eg `#[Route]`, `#[Entity]` etc works, but the Security attributes do not seem to work.

Comment: Which exact version of symfony are you using?

Comment: I am using Symfony 5.3.6 and Php 8.0.9

Comment: and the version of SensioFrameworkExtraBundle?

Comment: sensio/framework-extra-bundle        v5.6.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Support for PHP8 attributes in the `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` package are available only from version [6.1.0](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/commit/ec5a46706eb0fbfba327e08e8c66d432a69fcd1b). You likely just need to update it.